# Python KivyMD JSON changing json key/values from strings into methods so they are callable

Tags: dynamic, kivymd

```
'''
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

dict = {
    "Button Name": "Create Event",
   "Button Function": 'self.create_event'},
{
   "Button Name": "Find Event",
   "Button Function": "self.find_event"},
{
     "Button Name": "Create Player",
    "Button Function": "self.create_player"},
{
     "Button Name": "Find Player",
    "Button Function": "self.find_player"
}
class DemoBox(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DemoBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        for button in dict:
            btn = Button(text=button['Button Name'])
            btn.bind(on_press=button['Button Function'])
            self.add_widget(button)

    def create_event(self):
        print("Going to the Create Event Page")

    def create_player(self):
        print("Sending to create player page")

    def find_event(self):
        print("Heading to find event page")

    def find_player(self):
        print('We are in the Find Player page')

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DemoBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoApp().run()
```

I am getting an error stating that self.create_event() is not callable

the actual code will be saved in a .json file and contain far more buttons, and will hopefully save code editing.  Just allowing future buttons to be added by adding to the .json file / dict.  Then defining the function, which will change page / execute code.

Comment: First of all you should change the name of the var. `dict` (which is already a default token) with some other name, say `dict_`. Secondly, is it a typo or did you forget brackets around the var. `dict` ?

Comment: Well, the dict works fine for me.  Its the binding of the "Button Function" VALUE which is the name of the defined function below, being "callable" when added to the page as a widget.

I am receiving the error that says
Assertion Error: 'self.create_event' is not callable

I am wondering how I make it callable.  I am guessing that I have to assign the
dict.values to a variable and make an object, which would be holding a string, and call some sort of func() or partial() on that object?

Comment: 1. Of course the name `dict` will work here, but this is not recommended. You can check out [**PEP8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments). 2. If you don't put bracket around it, it will only take the first value, try printing it. 3. You can find the built-in function `getattr` quite handy here but with some obvious change.

Comment: I will try that out @Ap

Comment: What I was trying to have answered and still trying to have answered is, if I have a .json file with the KEY:VALUE pair being the 
KEY= string of name of button 
VALUE= string of function name to be called

Comment: count = "1"
for button, action in new_buttons.items():
  self.new_button = MDRaisedButton(font_style='Subtitle2', text=button,
                                               on_press=action,
                                               size_hint=(1, None), padding='10dp', )
self.root.ids.left_list.add_widget(self.new_button+count)
count += 1